# Can't create media using facebook instagram graph api

Tags: facebook, instagram, instagram-graph-api

I have a test Business App where I can query information about the user normally.
I can successfully authenticate the required scopes on my Facebook page.

Here are the scopes I asked for: `instagram_basic,instagram_content_publish,user_events,user_videos,user_posts`

However, when I try to create a post using [this api](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/instagram-api/guides/content-publishing#publish-photos), I get an error. Here's the request:

```
curl --location --request POST 'https://graph.facebook.com/me/media?access_token={ommited}' \
                --form 'image_url="https://cdn1.vectorstock.com/i/thumbs/59/70/flat-robot-vector-20655970.jpg"' \
                --form 'caption="nothing to see here :-"'
```

Response:

```
"error": {
        "message": "Unsupported post request. Object with ID 'me' does not exist, cannot be loaded due to missing permissions, or does not support this operation. Please read the Graph API documentation at https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api"
}
...
```

I tried the request with the user_id instead of `me` as well, but also doesn't work.

Comment: I'd suggest filing a bug report at https://developers.facebook.com/support/bugs/create

Answer (score 1):

Well, I figured it out.

Basically, when we query the `/media` endpoint, the api is expecting an "IG User" id. In this case, I'm using a FB User token, and therefore the API can't figure out who 'me' is. We can only really use "me" on objects that own `access_tokens` (namely, User and Page).

I solved this problem by passing my **instagram_business_account** id, which can be queried on the FB User endpoint (https://graph.facebook.com/me/?access_token=user_access_token) by passing the following fields:

```
fields=accounts{instagram_business_account{id}}
```

Which basically returns the accounts (that is, "Page"s) associated with the user and the "IG User" associated with those pages.

--

So, at last, the final request to actually create a Media Container will look something like this:

```
# Endpoint
https://graph.facebook.com/*instagram_business_id*/media
# replace instagram_business_id with the instagram_business_id you got upon querying the Graph API
# query params:
    
     - access_token=
     - image_url=https://cdn1.vectorstock.com/i/thumbs/59/70/flat-robot-vector-20655970.jpg
     - caption=your_image_caption
```

Comment: Well maybe you can help... When using  instagram_business_account so calling https://graph.facebook.com/".$instagram_business_account."/media?access_token=".$accessToken
and also image_url and caption in POST, I don't get back the container id... So can you edit your answer explaining what' you've done?

Comment: @Peter perhaps you could show the request you're trying to do, along with the response you're getting? Just upload it somewhere.